# 2009 Google logo is still used

Tags: bug, favicon

Clicking the "Join" option when you visit a stack exchange you're not a part of yet, gives you the option to sign in, with the same OAuth provider you used to sign in to other stack exchanges. The logo for Google is still the 2009 one:

[image: Join button]

#### Old Google favicon in confirmation page

[image: Old Google favicon in confirmation page]

The new Google favicon is actually [image: this one].
Please update it!

Comment: +1 The new logo is already used in the "Help us grow this site" widget in the right sidebar on beta sites. Example: https://writing.stackexchange.com/